# AWS IoT Authentication - Using own certificate not working

Tags: aws, authentication

I'm trying to set up AWS IoT authentication with using my own certificate according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-your-own.html). I've managed to register a CA, enabled it as well as set it to auto-register. Also, created device cert & key according to the docs. When I first connect my device using the freshly generated key & cert it won't work. No sign of connection. It should publish a message to the `$aws/events/certificates/registered/caCertificateID` topic. In the MQTT console I'm unable to see anything in that topic. I've also tried attaching a template according to the [JIT provisioning docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jit-provisioning.html), same, no luck, doesn't seem anything to be happening.

When I manually register the device cert (`aws iot register-certificate --certificate-pem file://deviceCert.pem --ca-certificate-pem file://rootCA.pem`) it is then able to connect to AWS.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use just-in-time registration or JIT provisioning setup ? The difference is [explained here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind, that when connecting the first time and trying to register a certificate with JIT you have to provide not only the device certificate but *also the CA certificate* you used to sign your device certificate (your CA in this case).
You can combine the 2 certificates with

```
cat deviceCert.crt caCert.crt > deviceAndCA.crt
```

as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/just-in-time-registration-of-device-certificates-on-aws-iot/).

OK, I'm a little late to the party as this question is a couple of months old, but I guess it still deserves an answer. I ran into the same problem and spent quite some time searching for the mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this question. I have also figured it out. :)

Comment: Late answers are always good - it shows the question is relevant to someone (and helps to spread the rep about so there are more people who can vote)

Answer (score 2):

**I ran into a similar problem with a different solution**

If you create a certificate using a default openssl.cnf, or some other mechanism that generates an SSL certificate such as PHP's openssl_csr_sign, make certain your generated certificate does not have the x509_extensions set to make a CA certificate.

After three days of banging my head against the wall, I discovered that Amazon IoT will reject any device certificate that has CA:true set.  Use OpenSSL to verify:

`openssl x509 -in deviceCertificate.pem -text -noout`

You should see something like this:

```
 X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
```

I hope this helps someone save some time.

Comment: Well, how do you change that? I changed the openssl config file but it showed me `An error occurred (CertificateValidationException) when calling the RegisterCACertificate operation: CA certificate is not valid. The CA certificate does not have the basicConstraints extension as true` when I tried to register the CA with AWS IoT.

Comment: You need basicConstraints extension to be true when you are creating a Certificate Authority, of course.  However, your AWS "Thing" cannot have a CA Certificate; it just needs a regular certificate.  Because of the default setting in openssl.cnf, I was accidentally making all of my Things certificates that were actually CA certificates, instead of ordinary certs.  If for some reason you need a CA cert as a Thing cert, I would suggest making two; one for sigining and one for authentication with AWS.